# Sort an array multidimension by key php

Tags: php, php-5.3, php-5.4

I have this array :

```
Array
(
  [26] => Array
    (
        [total_auctions] => 1
        [total_price] => 0
    )

  [24] => Array
    (
        [total_auctions] => 0
        [total_price] => 0
    )

  [25] => Array
    (
        [total_auctions] => 0
        [total_price] => 0
    )
)
```

I want to sort this array to be :

```
Array
(
[24] => Array
(
    [total_auctions] => 0
    [total_price] => 0
)
[25] => Array
(
    [total_auctions] => 0
    [total_price] => 0
)

[26] => Array
(
    [total_auctions] => 1
    [total_price] => 0
 )
)
```

I tried with `array_multisort` but not work. Can you help me please ? Thx in advance. I don't understand where is the problem, normally should work

Comment: Just `sort()` will do that

Comment: No @Thamilan, it's return `1`

Comment: Sort doesn't return any value. Use `sort($arr); print_r($arr);`

Answer (score -1):

Just use ksort() to sort any array keys

```
<?php 
$arr = array(
  '26' => array('total_auctions' => 1,'total_price' => 0),
  '24' => array('total_auctions' => 0,'total_price' => 0),
  '25' => array('total_auctions' => 0,'total_price' => 0)
  );
ksort($arr);
print '<pre>';print_r($arr);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Not work...it's return `1`

Comment: Yes, but it's change the key in place of `24,25,26` is put `0,1,2`

Comment: use uasort($arr, 'compare'); it will Sort an array with a user-defined comparison function and maintain index association

Comment: @HareaCosticla i also used same answer as Dharma Parmar solved it gives me correct answer with sorted keys 24,25,26. Also the probelm that you are getting 1 is that you are doing this print_r(sort($yourarray)) or echo(sort($yourarray)).